# SQL sort order based on multiple column values

Tags: t-sql

We have data sorted like the format below. The first column is our system numbering, the second column is a back end system numbering, and the third column signifies that the rows with a ParentCol value actually below to the matching row of Col1. (So item 20 has two additional parts, item 30 and item 50.)

```
Col1      Col2      ParentCol
10        100       NULL
20        200       NULL
30        201       20
40        300       NULL
50        202       20
10        400       NULL
...
```

This is just a small example - there can sometimes be hundreds of rows per order.  The application isn't handling this situation well from the standpoint of viewing the data in the UI.  Ideally, I would like to have the content sorted like this, with our ID number (Col1) being the primary sorting, but recognizing that the back-end ID number (Col2) should immediately follow when there is a ParentCol value matching our ID:

```
Col1      Col2      ParentCol
10        100       NULL
10        400       NULL
20        200       NULL
30        201       20
50        202       20
40        300       NULL
```

Using T-SQL, how would I write a query that returns the data as I need it? Because of the various numbering schemes and possible valid duplicate values in our numbering scheme, Col1, (but not the back-end column, Col2), I haven't been able to figure this one out.

Thank you,

Scott

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM @t 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ParentID IS NULL THEN col1 ELSE ParentID END, col2
```

Comment: +1, also, using COALESCE instead of CASE: `… ORDER BY COALESCE(ParentID, col1), col2`.